How to mock java reactor Flux using okhttp3 MockWebServer
We use spring boot application that uses webflux and java reactor. Spring application calls an external service that returns a Flux. We have examples of how to mock response using okhttp3 in our project when the response is Mono. However, when the response is Flux how do we mock the response?
When response is mono; we use mockwebserver.enque(json mock response).
When response is Flux; how do we enqueue the mocked json response.
